# Are the ,middle layers in Resnet even learning?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, resnet

The skip connections allows our gradient all the way from 152nd layers and feed through the initial 1st or 2nd layers of the CNN. But what about the middle layers? Backpropagations in these middle layers are totally irrelevant so are we even learning in resnet?

Answer (score 1):

Backpropagation in these middle layers aren't totally irrelevant. The basic idea of the relevance of the middle layers is that ResNet keeps improving its error-rate when adding new layers (from 5.71 top5 error with 34 layer to 4.49 top5 error with 152). Images have a lot of singularities and complexities, and the folks at Microsoft found out that, when you take care of the vanishing gradient problem (with the feed through) you can gain more knowledge throughout the network with more layers.

The ideia of adding the residual block, it's to prevent the vanishing gradient problem, when you are getting too many layers... But the middle layers are also updated on each training step, and they are also learning (usually high-level features).

Convolutional Neural Networks with lots of layers tend to overfit if the problem isn't too much complex, since its 152 layers have a capacity of learning a lot of different patterns.

Comment: this answer makes sense and kind of what I thought. I get the fact that more we add layers better it will get in predicting complex pattern but that will only happen if the network keeps adjusting itself which will only happen via backpropagation. So no backpropagation(due to the vanishing gradient which will happen in the middle layers) means no weight adjustment and so does it not kind of defeats the purpose of adding more layers?